# MySql READ_COMMITTED behaviour when incrementing a value

Tags: mysql, transactions

If I run the following statement twice in parallel in a MySql transaction with READ_COMMITTED, what result will I get?

```sql
UPDATE some_table set count = count + 1 where id = x;
```

Assuming the count before execution is `1`, which of these strategies does MySql use internally when incrementing a row value?

One with a race condition:

| Time | MySql Thread A | MySql Thread B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Select current `count` from table (1) | Select current `count` from table (1) |
| 2 | Increment `count` in memory (2) | Increment `count` in memory (2) |
| 3 | Row lock, update count = 2 | -- Blocked -- |
| 4 | -- Done -- | Row lock, update count = 2 |

One without a race condition:

| Time | Writer A | Writer B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Row lock | -- Blocked -- |
| 2 | Select current `count` from table (1) | -- Blocked -- |
| 3 | Increment `count` in memory (2) | -- Blocked -- |
| 4 | update count = 2 | -- Blocked -- |
| 5 | -- Done -- | Select current `count` from table (2) |
| 6 | -- Done -- | Increment `count` in memory (3) |
| 7 | -- Done -- | update count = 3 |

What guarantees does MySql's `READ_COMMITTED` isolation give in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Ff you are set on storing the number, use

```
UPDATE CATEGORY
SET count = count + 1
WHERE category_id = x
```

But I feel it's more efficient if you do this:

```
SELECT c.category_name,
COUNT(p.post_id) AS num_posts
FROM CATEGORY c
LEFT JOIN POSTS p ON p.category_id = c.category_id
```

reflecting the aggregate values of the database.

Comment: Thanks, but the examples in the question are the meant to represent what is going on in MySql internally when it executes the update statement `UPDATE some_table set count = count + 1 where id = x;`.  I have updated the question to be clearer